EF Core : retrieve products with all supplier prices for price comparison and identify cheapest supplier
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application using ABP framework and EF Core. I need to retrieve information about products and their suppliers for comparison purposes.
Specifically, I want to achieve the following:

Fetch a list of products
For each product, include a list showcasing all its suppliers and their respective prices
Additionally, identify the supplier with the cheapest price for each product.

I've tried using Pivot Kendo Grid, but I'm struggling to format the data into a user-friendly structure like a table for displaying all supplier prices.
I want the output to be a list of products, where each product has information about:
Product ID,Name
List of suppliers (each supplier in a column)
The ID and Price of the cheapest supplier (to be highlighted)

Something like:



Product ID
Product Name
Supplier 1
Supplier 2
Supplier 3
etc...




Product 1
MacBook
1,000$
1,100$
1,200$
etc...



How can I modify my EF Core query or further process the retrieved data to achieve the desired output format suitable for displaying a table of supplier prices with the cheapest one highlighted?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Additional information:

I'm using ABP framework.
Supplier numbers are unknown (dynamic)

Feel free to share any relevant code snippets or approaches you've tried.
Thanks!

"How can I modify my EF Core query " - what query exactly? There is no query in the question. Also EF Core is not ideal tool for generation of results with dynamic number of columns.

" into a user-friendly structure " - also arguably table with dynamic number of suppliers is not that user-friendly.

Hi @GuruStron the query is a normal query that retreive data in tabuler format and Pivot grid display it in columner as per the showcosing table.

Table data in mentioend format will be enough for my needs however I'm open for suggestions?

As I see from Telerik documentation, you have to send just flat data, something like that : Product ID, Product Name, Supplier, Price. Pivot Engine should combine data to needed view automatically. I was surprised that they support only OLAP data to query from database only needed parts. For example DevExpress Pivot grid can be connected to IQueryable source and all needed grouping and filtering will be applied automatically.


EF Core : retrieve products with all supplier prices for price
comparison and identify cheapest supplier.

Well based on your scenario and description I have tried to investigate your  issue and here is the findings of my investigation.
According to your requirement, we should have following class:
public class ProductWithPrices
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public List<SupplierPrice> Suppliers { get; set; }
}

public class SupplierPrice
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

As its a demo example, so I am using the demo data without using DbContext.
In order to implement the query, within the Index action, I have created a list of ProductWithPrices objects. Each product contains an ID, name, and a list of suppliers with their respective prices.
For each product, I have determined the cheapest supplier by sorting the suppliers based on their prices and selecting the one with the lowest price.
Finally, I have stored the cheapest supplier ID and price for each product.
Let's have a look in practice:
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var productsWithPrices = new List<ProductWithPrices>
            {
                new ProductWithPrices
                {
                    ProductId = 1,
                    ProductName = "Product 1",
                    Suppliers = new List<SupplierPrice>
                    {
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 1, SupplierName = "Supplier 1", Price = 1000 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 2, SupplierName = "Supplier 2", Price = 1100 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 3, SupplierName = "Supplier 3", Price = 1200 }
                    }
                },
                new ProductWithPrices
                {
                    ProductId = 2,
                    ProductName = "Product 2",
                    Suppliers = new List<SupplierPrice>
                    {
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 1, SupplierName = "Supplier 1", Price = 2000 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 2, SupplierName = "Supplier 2", Price = 1900 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 3, SupplierName = "Supplier 3", Price = 2100 }
                    }
                },
                new ProductWithPrices
                {
                    ProductId = 3,
                    ProductName = "Product 3",
                    Suppliers = new List<SupplierPrice>
                    {
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 1, SupplierName = "Supplier 1", Price = 3000 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 2, SupplierName = "Supplier 2", Price = 3100 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 3, SupplierName = "Supplier 3", Price = 2900 }
                    }
                },
                new ProductWithPrices
                {
                    ProductId = 4,
                    ProductName = "Product 4",
                    Suppliers = new List<SupplierPrice>
                    {
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 1, SupplierName = "Supplier 1", Price = 4000 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 2, SupplierName = "Supplier 2", Price = 4100 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 3, SupplierName = "Supplier 3", Price = 4200 }
                    }
                },
                new ProductWithPrices
                {
                    ProductId = 5,
                    ProductName = "Product 5",
                    Suppliers = new List<SupplierPrice>
                    {
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 1, SupplierName = "Supplier 1", Price = 5000 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 2, SupplierName = "Supplier 2", Price = 4900 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 3, SupplierName = "Supplier 3", Price = 4800 }
                    }
                },
                new ProductWithPrices
                {
                    ProductId = 6,
                    ProductName = "Product 6",
                    Suppliers = new List<SupplierPrice>
                    {
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 1, SupplierName = "Supplier 1", Price = 6000 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 2, SupplierName = "Supplier 2", Price = 6100 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 3, SupplierName = "Supplier 3", Price = 6200 }
                    }
                },
                new ProductWithPrices
                {
                    ProductId = 7,
                    ProductName = "Product 7",
                    Suppliers = new List<SupplierPrice>
                    {
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 1, SupplierName = "Supplier 1", Price = 7000 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 2, SupplierName = "Supplier 2", Price = 7100 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 3, SupplierName = "Supplier 3", Price = 7200 }
                    }
                },
                new ProductWithPrices
                {
                    ProductId = 8,
                    ProductName = "Product 8",
                    Suppliers = new List<SupplierPrice>
                    {
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 1, SupplierName = "Supplier 1", Price = 8000 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 2, SupplierName = "Supplier 2", Price = 7900 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 3, SupplierName = "Supplier 3", Price = 7800 }
                    }
                },
                new ProductWithPrices
                {
                    ProductId = 9,
                    ProductName = "Product 9",
                    Suppliers = new List<SupplierPrice>
                    {
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 1, SupplierName = "Supplier 1", Price = 9000 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 2, SupplierName = "Supplier 2", Price = 9100 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 3, SupplierName = "Supplier 3", Price = 9200 }
                    }
                },
                new ProductWithPrices
                {
                    ProductId = 10,
                    ProductName = "Product 10",
                    Suppliers = new List<SupplierPrice>
                    {
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 1, SupplierName = "Supplier 1", Price = 10000 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 2, SupplierName = "Supplier 2", Price = 10100 },
                        new SupplierPrice { SupplierId = 3, SupplierName = "Supplier 3", Price = 10200 }
                    }
                }
            };

    //Query for Processing data to identify the cheapest supplier for each product
    var formattedProducts = productsWithPrices.Select(p => new
    {
        ProductId = p.ProductId,
        ProductName = p.ProductName,
        SupplierPrices = p.Suppliers.ToDictionary(
            sp => sp.SupplierName,
            sp => sp.Price
        ),
        CheapestSupplierId = p.Suppliers.OrderBy(sp => sp.Price).FirstOrDefault()?.SupplierId,
        CheapestPrice = p.Suppliers.OrderBy(sp => sp.Price).FirstOrDefault()?.Price
    }).ToList();

    // I am using string builder to create HTML table
    var tableHeader = new StringBuilder();
    tableHeader.AppendLine("<tr><th>Product ID</th><th>Product Name</th>");

    var supplierNames = formattedProducts
        .SelectMany(p => p.SupplierPrices.Keys)
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(name => name)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var supplierName in supplierNames)
    {
        tableHeader.AppendLine($"<th>{supplierName}</th>");
    }
    tableHeader.AppendLine("<th>Cheapest Supplier</th><th>Cheapest Price</th></tr>");

    var tableRows = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var product in formattedProducts)
    {
        tableRows.AppendLine("<tr>");
        tableRows.AppendLine($"<td>{product.ProductId}</td>");
        tableRows.AppendLine($"<td>{product.ProductName}</td>");

        foreach (var supplierName in supplierNames)
        {
            var price = product.SupplierPrices.ContainsKey(supplierName)
                ? product.SupplierPrices[supplierName].ToString("C")
                : "-";
            tableRows.AppendLine($"<td>{price}</td>");
        }

        tableRows.AppendLine($"<td>{product.CheapestSupplierId}</td>");
        tableRows.AppendLine($"<td>{product.CheapestPrice?.ToString("C")}</td>");
        tableRows.AppendLine("</tr>");
    }

    var table = $"<table class='table table-striped'>{tableHeader}{tableRows}</table>";

    ViewData["ProductTable"] = table;
    return View();
}

Note: The sole purpose is the guide you how we could implement that, so I have used string builder and bind that within @Html.Raw for quick demo, you could modify based on your preference.
View:
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Product Prices";
}

<h2>Product Prices</h2>

<div>
    @Html.Raw(ViewData["ProductTable"])
</div>

Output:

Note: As said earlier, this is not the exact solution what you have asked for. I am trying to show you the way how should you proceed. Feel free to modify the given code the way you want or which suits to your framework.
